# Can I add Google Moderator to MediaWiki?

Tags: widget, mediawiki

Can I add [Google Moderator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Moderator) to [MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki)? Is there a Widget for it?

Is it possible somehow to add it to my MediaWiki? Or do I need to create a new Widget for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've already asked the same question [elsewhere and got an answer](http://groups.google.com/group/mediawiki-widgets/browse_thread/thread/1d24635ba9f19a09#).

For reference, the reply was:

> They do have an API, but I don't see any widgets on the site.
>   You can try creating a widget yourself if you like, but it's definitely not
>   an easy task:
>   http://code.google.com/apis/moderator/

Comment: true .. and you want a medal for knowing that ? lol j/k

Thanks for the effort :)